# how to improve performance when create test-generator?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I want to create a unit test generator use white-box testing. But when create testcases for a big method (many for, while,..), how can I improve performance (time, result)? 
Has anyone got any experiences of something similar to this?

Comment: What would a unit-test generator do?

Comment: I created a tool, it generates testcases for a method use white-box testing. For example:
Int function(a, b){
// code
}
When use this tool, it will return a list of testcases, [(1,2), (3,4),...]
But with a big method this tool takes a long time, so I want to improve execution time of test generator.